# Flutter AnimatedContainer / AnimatedOpacity Delay animation

Tags: flutter, animation, delay

How do you delay animation in Flutter.

The below provides an animation of the opacity of a container. I have used a bool _reduced in this case to change the speed of the animation based on that bool variable. But I don't want to change the speed, I want to simply delay the animation one way round by 500 milliseconds. I can't see anyway of easily making an animation delay.

```
AnimatedOpacity(
   duration: _reduced ? Duration(milliseconds: 120) : Duration(milliseconds: 800),
   opacity: _reduced ? 0 : 1,
   child: Text('hi di hi),
}
```

There is obviously more to what this does than I have shown above but essentially I want to do something like this:

```
   AnimatedOpacity(
       duration: _reduced ? Duration(milliseconds: 120) : Duration(milliseconds: 120, delay: 500),
       opacity: _reduced ? 0 : 1,
       child: Text('hi di hi),
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried out curves which helps to decide the rate of change its animating [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedOpacity-class.html)

Comment: That is one way to do it, just not as exact and customisable as I'd prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a delay varibale for your stateful widget: `Duration delay =...;`

then when your condition to change the opacity becomes true (for example inside the `onTap` property of some button), create a timer that calls `setState` after `delay` ms :

```
onTap:(){
        Timer t = Timer(
            Duration(milliseconds:delay),(){
          setState((){
            _opacity = myNewValue;
          });
        });
      }
```

**Update**: since you said you want to stick to the provider package, I assume that you are storing your UI state (in this case the opacity) in some `ChangeNotifier`, so in this case just replace `setState` with a call to your change notifier:

```
 onTap:(){
            Timer t = Timer(
                Duration(milliseconds:delay),(){
              context.read<MyUIStateChangeNotifier>().setOpacity(newOpacityValue);
          }
```

and just as a side note, this small detail does not need a change notifier to hold it, since it is only relevant to the current screen, change notifiers are usually used to carry state across multiple screens in order not to pass the state every time in the constructor

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to keep it all strictly to provider package.

Comment: this can also apply to provider, just replace setState with a call to your change notifier, I will edit the answer to show how

Comment: @RIK see the updated answer